# discord.py Logging Names With Commands And Args

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

I Need Help im trying to make a command that only people with a determinated role can execute.

i tried doing this:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('$jadd'):
        with open('info.txt', 'a') as info:
            info.write(message.content)
            print("Aggiunto " + message.author.mention + "alla Lista")
```

what i wanted to do is making a command that if i do $jadd (Arg) then will add only the arg to the file

but i wanted in the file to look like this:

"ARG",

so the program could easily read it

what happened is that when i type the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is vague but I'll share one way I know to solve this.

Get the argument and instead of storing the name of the role to your file, use the name to find within the roles of the server the specified role then get that role's id and store it in a json file, this way you can both check if that role actually exists and not have to deal with capitalization of the name.

Comment: i am new so i dont really know what do you mean im learning python and discord.py at the same time if you could please explain more to me! Thank You in advance!

Comment: what i wanted to do is like put the name in a file

when a guy does a command and if he is not in the file he will get a message, if he is in the file the command will work but i would like to add people in the file with a command and not manually